# how to use Pixi.js passing data to the handler

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

use pixi.js create sprite and

```
 var sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(textureSprite);
    sprite.buttonMode = true;
    sprite.position.x = _.provinces[0].posX;
    sprite.position.y = _.provinces[0].posY;
    // make the button interactive...
    sprite.interactive = true;
    sprite
        // set the mousedown and touchstart callback...
        .on('mousedown',onButtonDown)
        .on('touchstart',onButtonDown);
```

how can I pass argument to event handler function onButtonDown?
The same event handler can be bound to an element multiple times.

Comment: You don't pass arguments to callback functions. Pixi itself will call the callback function when an event occurs.

Comment: Pixi calls the `mousedown` and `touchstart` functions with one [InteractionData](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/docs/classes/InteractionData.html) parameter. You can get some info out of that, like the type of the [event](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/docs/classes/Event.html).

Comment: it is basically impossible as the callback is called from within Pixi. Why you need it? Based on your needs, you have different ways to achieve the result.

Answer (score 3):

How about using an anonymous function?

```
sprite.on('mousedown',function(e) { onButtonDown(e,"hello"); });
```

You could also set a property on your sprite and then pick the property up from your `onButtonDown` method using `e.target` (which gives you the sprite that has been interacted with):

```
sprite.myCustomProperty = "hello"; 

// And then in your mousedown method: 
var onButtonDown = function(e) {
  var customProperty = e.target.myCustomProperty; 
}
```